# Integrating Visual Studio 2013 project into a Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am having issues when integrating a VS 2013 project (database first, MVC 4, .NET 4, EF6) into the areas folder of a VS 2010 project (code first, MVC 4, .NET 4, EF6). I should point out that I had to switch to 2013 for this second project because I could not get VS 2010 using MVC4/.NET4/EF6 properly create an EDMX for database first, but that is another isssue I sidestepped by using VS2013.

So now the 2031 Proj is built and ready to be integrated into the larger ecosystem...

Lets call the VS 2010 project MainProj and the VS 2013 project ChildProj

Basically I have taken the MainProj's dll and added it as a reference in ChildProj.

Then I changed all the namespaces to reflect the 2010's name (MainProj.Areas.ChildProj.whatever) I updated the routing in ChildProjAreaRegistration.cs

I added authentication code in the Global.asax under "Session_Start" that uses domain authentication but I get this error (which I cannot fix)...

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The (SAMAccountName=) search filter is invalid.
```

Does anybody know of any issues with VS 2013 and 2010 or 2013 and domain authentication issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug in your Session_Start auth code. Can you update the question with the code that is throwing the exception? There is only a very slim chance this is related to Visual Studio and a very high chance of being a simple bug in your code.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/66e9zQ

Here is the fiddle of my code.